# SRV records not populating correctly

Tags: domain-name-system, sip, lync, srv-record

I have a lync box with a SIP SRV record that isn't working for a significant portion of clients, despite their ability to resolve the FQDN of the edge server. What could cause inconsistent resolution of SRV records or an inability to resolve SRV records while still being able to pull DNS for the domain?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you haven't yet troubleshot from an affected client directly?  They are able to pull an A record but not SRV?  Can they pull any SRV records from the DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for locally connected clients, or remote clients connecting via an edge server?